# Using map issues

Tags: java

I am using a map to store information about an army and then pass the map as a parameter to a function to create an army. The input is the following:

```
Humans : {30,40}
Elfs: {20,40,60}
Humans: {10}
```

The method that i am using to store the information is not working well, because when i add a key with another value, it's creating a new object because i am using a new instance o that class. Can anyone can help me fix this?

```
public class InputInformation {

    public static Map<CreatureFactory, ArrayList<Integer>> description;

    public InputInformation(){
        description = new HashMap<CreatureFactory,ArrayList<Integer>>();
    }

    public static  Map<CreatureFactory, ArrayList<Integer>> createArmy(BufferedReader buffer) 
            throws IOException,NumberFormatException {
        String option;
        CreatureFactory factory;
        ArrayList<Integer> warriors;
        Map<CreatureFactory, ArrayList<Integer>> description = new HashMap<CreatureFactory, ArrayList<Integer>>();
        while(true){
            createArmysMenu();
            while((option = buffer.readLine()) != null){
                switch(option){
                case "H":
                    factory = new HumansFactory(); 
                    warriors = getTroopNumberOfWarriors(buffer);
                    description.put(factory, warriors); 
                    break;
                case "E":
                    factory = new ElfsFactory();
                    warriors = getTroopNumberOfWarriors(buffer);
                    description.put(factory, warriors);
                    break;
                case "D":
                    factory = new DwarfsFactory();
                    warriors = getTroopNumberOfWarriors(buffer);
                    description.put(factory, warriors);
                    break;
                case "O":
                    factory = new OrcsFactory();
                    warriors = getTroopNumberOfWarriors(buffer);
                    description.put(factory, warriors);
                    break;
                case "W":
                    factory = new WargsFactory();
                    warriors = getTroopNumberOfWarriors(buffer);
                    description.put(factory, warriors);
                    break;
                case "F":
                    System.out.println("Your army has been created");
                    showPrincipalMenu();                    
                    return description;
                default: 
                    System.out.println("Mistmatch");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

    }
    private static ArrayList<Integer> getTroopNumberOfWarriors( BufferedReader buffer) 
            throws NumberFormatException, IOException {
        Integer numberOfWarriors;
        ArrayList<Integer> warriors = null;     
        while(true){
            enterNumberOfWarriors();
            numberOfWarriors = Integer.parseInt(buffer.readLine());
            if(numberOfWarriors == -1){
                createArmysMenu();
                break;
            } else { 
                if(warriors == null){
                    warriors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                    warriors.add(numberOfWarriors);
                } else {
                    warriors.add(numberOfWarriors);
                }
            }

        }
        return warriors;
    }

    public static void showPrincipalMenu(){
        System.out.println("To create the free army press 1");
        System.out.println("To create the dark army press 2");
        System.out.println("To start the fight, press 0");
    }

    public static void createArmysMenu(){
        System.out.println("To add a Humans troop, press H");
        System.out.println("To add an Elfs troop, press E");
        System.out.println("To add an Dwarfs troop, press D");
        System.out.println("To add an Orcs troop, press O");
        System.out.println("To add an Wargs troop, press W");
        System.out.println("When you've done adding the troops, press F");
    }

    public static void enterNumberOfWarriors(){
        System.out.println("Enter the number of warriors for this troop");
        System.out.println("To add a new troop press -1");
    }
```

Comment: What do you want the description to have after inputting? `{HumansFactory: [30,40,10], ElfsFactory: [20,40,60]}`?

Comment: Yes. That is what i want to obtain. And i really have to use instances of classes as keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about having a `creatureMap` mapping the creature type/id to the `CreatureFactory` and using the same `CreatureFactory` object in the `description` map instead of creating a new one each time

```
Map<String, CreatureFactory> creatureMap = new HashMap<String, CreatureFactory>();
creatureMap.put("H", new HumansFactory());
creatureMap.put("E", new ElfsFactory());
creatureMap.put("D", new DwarfsFactory());
creatureMap.put("O", new OrcsFactory());
creatureMap.put("W", new WargsFactory());

// inside the loop
CreatureFactory factory = creatureMap.get(option);
if ( null == factory ) {
    if ( "F".equals(option) {
            System.out.println("Your army has been created");
            showPrincipalMenu();                    
            return description;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Mistmatch");
            break;
        } 
    ArrayList<Integer> warriors = description.get(factory);
    if ( null == warriors ) {
        // not added before
        warriors = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        description.put(factory, warriors);
    }
    warriors.addAll(getTroopNumberOfWarriors(buffer));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CreatureFactory and maybe their child classes probably miss hashCode, equals.

From your code `option` seems the best key.

Answer (score -2):

don't use instances as a key, every instance have different memory address so it will be another one, try using the class name `CreatureFactory.class.getName()`  or some other string

Comment: It's no Problem to use instances as keys in a Map as log as the hashCode() does not change. Also you could use the class object. Strings as key are also ok, but they are not very type-safe.